# using exit() function while debugging

Tags: c, memory-leaks, exit

I'm working on a c project.  when the program runs normally it does cleanup at the end of the program.  It cleans up curl and mysql, and free()s char arrays, etc.

When I'm developing new routines, I'm allocating resources that should be cleaned up at the end of the program.  But in order to see what's going on with the new routines, I'm printing out various things and then calling: 
exit(0);

My question is, when I compile the code with these unceremonious exit commands, is the linux environment smart enough to deallocate the resources that would have been de-allocated at the end of my program?  Or am I developing a leak in the system memory?

Comment: short answer: yes. exiting terminates all sockets & pipes & frees all memory allocated by the program.

Comment: There are certain shared resources that might leak (such as files created that didn't get deleted, or IPC resources that didn't get released), but otherwise yes. If you are a child process, and your parent doesn't reap you, you will leak process table entries.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I've been occasionally checking for the process using ps, and it's not showing up.  So, I assume I'm not hurting the system too much.  I've probably exited the program this way about 100 times today, and don't see any ill effects yet.  So, apparently, so far so good.  Or did I miss something that jxh said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the memory will be freed, but instead of being relinquished by the process, it will be reaped by the Operating System at some point in time after the process exits.

In extreme cases, this can have RAM not associated with a process, but temporarily used accumulate bogging down the Operating System.  This is really only a major concern in "very" legacy operating systems (think 20+ years old).

In many cases, file handles are in shorter supply than RAM, and you might have an issue when waiting for a new file handle.  But again, most modern operating systems will eventually reclaim the open file handles.

Now, there are items (IPC structures, like [semaphores](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node26.html), [shared memory](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node27.html), etc.) which might not be cleaned up in an unceremonious exit, but you typically would know about such things, if you were using them at all.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I'm not using any of those (IPC, semaphores or shared memory).  This is a single threaded app at the moment.  Also fairly recent linux distro (less than 2 years anyway). I really appreciate the answers.

Comment: @mikekehrli Glad it helped!